# Errores al loguear

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Todo me funciona bien pero cuando inicio sesión es como si pusiera los datos incorrectos y los datos que coloco en el formulario son iguales a los que hay en la base de datos, entonces lo que pasa es que en `ingreso.php` me pasa de una vez al else y me pone el texto de `<h1>ERROR DE AUTENTIFICACIÓN</h1>`

[image: Base de datos]

```php
//conex.php
<?php 
// Defino las constantes de conexion=+
$server="localhost";
$user="root";
$basedatos="programming_for_all"; //Aqui coloco el nombre de la base de datos de mi proyecto
$pass="";
$msj="No se ha encontrado enlace con el servidor o la base de datos";

//Constructor de conexion, utilizamos el mètodo mysqli() para realizar la conexiòn 
$conexion= new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$basedatos) or die ($msj);

$acento= $conexion->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
//Si no se puede conectar, envìa un mensaje de error 
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
}
 ?>

//ingreso.php
<?php
$NAME = $_POST['name'];
$LASTNAME = $_POST['lastname'];
$EMAIL = $_POST['email'];
$PASSWORD = $_POST['password']; 
session_start();
$_SESSION['name']=$NAME;

include("../../../Modelo/conex.php");

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Nombre_us='$NAME' & Apellido_us='$LASTNAME' & Correo_us='$EMAIL' & Clave_us='$PASSWORD'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if($filas){
    ?>
    <h1 class="ok">¡Te has inscrito correctamente!</h1>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <h1>ERROR DE AUTENTIFICACIÓN</h1>
    <?php
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

```
//login.php
<div class="box-ingreso">
<div class="ingreso-box">
    <img class="logo" src="../vista/assets/media/img/Website logone.jfif" alt="Logo de progamacion">
    <h1>Ingresa aquí</h1>
    <form action="../vista/assets/datos/ingreso.php" method="post">
        <!--Nombre-->
        <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input class="Nombre"  name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre">
        <!---->
        <!--Apellido-->
        <label for="Apellido">Apellido</label>
        <input class="Apellido"  name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu apellido">
        <!---->
        <!--Correo-->
        <label for="Correo">Correo</label>
        <input class="Correo"  name="email" type="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo electronico">
        <!---->   
        <!--Contraseña-->
        <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
        <input class="contraseña" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña">
        <!--Ingreso-->
        <center><button type="Submit" class="submit" name="login">Ingresar</button></center> 
                
        <a href="">¿Ha olvidado su contraseña?</a><br>
        <a href="../vista/registro.php">Registrarse</a>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto devuelve un número de filas: `$filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);` y no un valor booleano de `true`o `false`, por lo tanto no debes usarlo asi: `if($filas){`  sino así: `if($filas>0){` para que se cumpla una condición booleana. Por lo demás el hecho de guardar una contraseña sin aplicar ningun tipo de cifrado en modo texto es muy peligroso y nada recomendable. Busca ejemplos sobre **password_verify()** para mejorar eso.

Comment: Me sigue tirando el 
`else {
    ?>
    <h1>ERROR DE AUTENTIFICACIÓN</h1>
    <?php
}`

Comment: Cambia los `&` por `AND` en tu consulta SQL a ver si con eso funciona

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias

Comment: [En MySQL el *`Y lógico`*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and) se escribe con `AND` o con `&&` (nótese que son dos `&` no una). Lo más estándar es escribir `AND`. Por otra parte, tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*, considera usar consultas preparadas para neutralizar ese riesgo. Y, para saber si hay registros lo mejor es una consulta basada en `COUNT(*)` , en mysqli a veces `num_rows` depende del buffer, y podría darte `0` aunque no haya filas si no metes los resultados en el buffer antes.